# Images in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

Does anyone know of a way to rotate an image in ExtJs inside an `Ext.Img` component? The code I have right now is:

```
    xtype:'image',
    id: 'south_image',
    src: '/Home/DefaultImage',
    region: 'south',
    width: 700,
    height: 200
```

Answer (score 2):

use below code

```
xtype:'image',
id: 'south_image',
src: '/Home/DefaultImage',
region: 'south',
width: 700,
height: 200,
style: {
    transform: rotate(45deg),
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg),
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg),
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg),
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Image rotation is possible using css. Set style of your image like

```
transform:rotate(180deg)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rotate a `Ext.draw.Component` like so:

```
Ext.create('Ext.draw.Component', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    id: 'rotateImg',
    viewBox: false,
    padding: 20,
    items: [{
        type: 'image',
        src: 'http://www.sencha.com/img/apple-touch-icon.png',
        width: 200,
        height: 200
    }]
});

Ext.create('Ext.slider.Single', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    hideLabel: true,
    width: 400,
    minValue: 0,
    maxValue: 360,
    value: 0,
    listeners: {
        change: function (slider, value) {
            var sprite = Ext.getCmp('rotateImg').surface.items.first();
            sprite.setAttributes({
                rotation: {
                    degrees: value
                }
            }, true);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK there is no way to rotate that via ExtJs given that the img is generated dynamically, you can, of course rotate it on your server, that should be something trivial or, fall back to rotate it on canvas and, then add it to your component.

Comment: Downvoted? Explain, please. He asked for a way to rotate an image in Ext, not a component, not a way to rotate images in CSS and, in Ext, there no way to do it.

Comment: There is a way using the draw library.

Comment: He was clearly asking how to rotate an image (xtype: 'image') not how to use another kind of Ext component. And no, there is no way to do it in ExtJs without using style (AKA CSS) or do as i said, do not use downvote whe you don't pay attention to what you are doing...